# iterate through NavigateUrls on Page_PreRender and change style

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm not sure if this is at all possible (there may be a different way to acheive it) but is there a way to iterate though all hyperlinks on Page_PreRender and if the NavigateUrl matches the file name then I can add a class to the link to show this as the active page.

Or even better, iterate through all hyperlink NavigateUrls within a certain DIV.

I can do it individually but that would take too long as there are so many links and be too hard to manage:

```
   Protected Sub Page_PreRender(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender

        Dim filePath As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Path

        If filePath = "/" & hMembership.NavigateUrl Then
            hMembership.CssClass = "active"
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in the Page_PreRender:

```
    Dim filePath As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Path

    For Each Control As Control In Me.Form.Controls
        If TypeOf (Control) Is HyperLink Then
            With TryCast(Control, HyperLink)
                If .NavigateUrl = filePath Then
                    .CssClass = "active"
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next Control
```

Comment: Thanks Lefty, that put me on the right path with a few changes/additions.